# PHP | FPDF : Numberings in fpdf table

Tags: php, fpdf

I am having trouble in finding out on how to produce the output that I desired.

here is the example output:

[image]

the pdf file is generated through fpdf.

my question is how I can include a numbering in the table just like the picture above.

here are the codes I have so far..

query:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT tb_record_grade.*, tb_student.* FROM tb_record_grade 
                    INNER JOIN tb_student ON tb_record_grade.student_no=tb_student.student_no 
                    WHERE tb_record_grade.class_record_id = '$class_id' AND tb_record_grade.term = '$term'
                    AND tb_student.status = 'Active'
                    GROUP BY tb_student.stud_fname 
                    ORDER BY tb_student.stud_lname");
```

Tables:

```
    $pdf->Cell(45,5,'Student Name',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,'Course',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,'Rating',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(45,5,'Remark',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,'Signature',1,'','C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $fname = $row['stud_fname'];
    $lname = $row['stud_lname'];
    $course = $row['course_and_year'];
    $grade = $row['grade'];
    $remark = $row['remark'];
    $sig = "";

    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
    $pdf->Cell(45,5,$fname." ".$lname,1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$course,1,'','');
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$grade,1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(45,5,$remark,1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$sig,1,'','C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    }
```

any ideas will be a big help, thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create a new cell and use db id for each line:

```
$pdf->Cell(45,5,'Id',1,'','C');    
$pdf->Cell(45,5,'Student Name',1,'','C');
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Course',1,'','C');
$pdf->Cell(30,5,'Rating',1,'','C');
$pdf->Cell(45,5,'Remark',1,'','C');
$pdf->Cell(40,5,'Signature',1,'','C');
$pdf->Ln();
$count = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $count;
    $fname = $row['stud_fname'];
    $lname = $row['stud_lname'];
    $course = $row['course_and_year'];
    $grade = $row['grade'];
    $remark = $row['remark'];
    $sig = "";
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
    $pdf->Cell(45,5,$id,1);
    $pdf->Cell(45,5,$fname." ".$lname,1);
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$course,1,'','');
    $pdf->Cell(30,5,$grade,1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(45,5,$remark,1,'','C');
    $pdf->Cell(40,5,$sig,1,'','C');
    $pdf->Ln();
    $count++;
}
```